# how to receive an event while moving through buttons

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a piano app in android. I have just 8 notes and 8 buttons for each note. I implemented onTouch for every button, and there is no problem when I just touch one button. But when I touch a button and move my finger to the next one, than the onTouch function for that button is not called and it is ignored. How can I manage to play notes during sliding my finger on the buttons without taking my finger up? I am really stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

In your onTouch override, make sure you're checking for ACTION_MOVE events, and not just ACTION_DOWN. You'll need to keep track of which ones have been entered and left to make sure you don't play the notes repeatedly for ACTION_MOVE events of the same drag-entry.